# Adding restriction on who can access form submission information on Wagtail CMS

Tags: django, wagtail

I have a form page in my web application that is using Django and Wagtail. Is there a way to have a way to restrict or manage which Wagtail users can access the form submission data? Thank you

So far I can't find anything that will help me answer my question rather than adding permission in the code base